# Non-screenview events with Google Tag Manager on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-tag-manager

we're trying to use GTM on iOS to track non-screenview events using the data layer and cannot get this to work. First, here's our call to GTM:

```
NSLog(@"voted!");
NSLog(@"question: %@, answer: %@",self.question.question,selectedAnswer.answer);
[[ATITracking instance] trackEventWithTagManager:@"didVote" parameters:@{@"questionValue":self.question.question,@"voteValue":selectedAnswer.answer}];
```

We have 2 data layer variables set in GTM for the questionValue and the voteValue. See:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jru5a06vs1bfmm3/variables.jpg?dl=0

And here's our trigger with the event set to didVote:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ydxml4yemji2f5/trigger.jpg?dl=0

And our event tag uses the trigger from above (cannot post link due to rep limit.)

Has anyone seen a non-screenview event tracked successfully in iOS using GTM? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Events are working for me with no problems. This is slightly modified code from the GTM iOS SDK example

```
-(void) logEvent:(NSString*) event withProperties:(NSDictionary*) properties {
    NSMutableDictionary* eventProperties = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"event": @"customEvent",@"eventCategory":@"User action",@"eventName":event}];
    if (properties) {
        [eventProperties addEntriesFromDictionary:properties];
    }
    TAGDataLayer* dataLayer = self.tagManager.dataLayer;
    [dataLayer push:eventProperties];
}
```

Based on GTM documentation https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#events event category and event action must not be empty. I didn't see any events in GA until I configured these parameters in my tag and started pushing them from the client. 
Hope it helps.

Please see attached screenshot of my tag:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dmytro. Would you mind posting a screenshot of your tag UI in GTM please?

Comment: What’s the correlation between your dictionary’s `eventCategory` and `{{event_category}}` shown in GTM? Hugely confused at present, any help appreciated!

Comment: @lukech `eventCategory` is a Data Layer Variable which will take value of the `eventCategory` (User action in may case) from `eventProperties` dictionary in my example. Hope it helps